# How to use Adobe AIR to make an app using native java code in Android?

Tags: android, flash, air, flash-builder, air-native-extension

Let me set the context - I have been tasked with refactoring an app which plays .swf files. Currently, the app is split into two apks - one which lists the files and another which plays the .swf files. The second - player APK is an Adobe AIR app developed using Flash builder, Flex and ActionScript. I've got to find a way to combine the two apps into one for convenience of end user. However, I can't find any way to do that - combining an app developed in ActionScript into java code. The Flash builder simply spits out an .apk file, but no native code.

I came across [Native extensions for Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ane-android-devices.html), which I thought was the way to make Adobe AIR apps using java code, but turned out to just a way to add functionality to existing Adobe AIR apps using native code.

I found [an app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.issess.flashplayer) which is in some way using Adobe AIR's runtime to play .swf files natively in their app.

So, I'm guessing there is a way to access Adobe AIR runtime via java. However, I can't find any examples or documentation.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Adobe's `AIR` uses Java & Android SDK to compile Android apps (apk) from ActionScript 3 code. Such an app could load SWF since it would naturally support all Adobe formats (swf, flv, etc). It can't be done the other way round (Android SDK using AIR) as you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but probably scaleform is waht you are looking for http://help.autodesk.com/view/SCLFRM/ENU/?guid=__scaleform_help_getting_started_installation_usage_sdk_mobiles_sdk_android_html